Получить название файла из списка Python
У меня есть такой код:
import glob

txt_files = glob.glob('*.rpf')
print(txt_files)

которые получает файлы с расширением .rpf в виде списка:
['ptfx.rpf', 'ptfx_hi.rpf', 'ptfx_lo.rpf', 'update.rpf']

и мне надо сделать так, чтобы с помощью например input пользователь ввёл 0 и ему выдало название файла ptfx.rpf.
Помогите мне реализовать, пожалуйста.

Как вариант:
import glob
from pprint import pprint

# ---------------------> vvvv <---- установите нужное вам <------------------
txt_files = glob.glob('*.docx')
txt_files = { k: v for k, v in enumerate(txt_files)}
pprint(txt_files)


flag = True
while flag:
    try:
        index = int(input("\nВведите порядковый номер файла для выбора: "))

        print(f'\nВыбран index = {index}; filename = {txt_files[index]}\n')
        flag = False
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'\nВведите правильно номер; \n\t{e}\n')
        if not txt_files: flag = False



спасибо огромное

@embernxck пожалуйста.  Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете,
как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour
